# Spam Filtering Example Using Encog Framework

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, spam-prevention, encog

I am looking for an example on how to use Encog Framework to create a simple spam filtering/ classification or clustering application.  I haven't been able to find anything on google.

I have also purchased Jeff Heaton's book, Programming Neural Networks with Encog3 in C#, but I can't find any examples for such an application.

Can anyone provide any info on a simple application how to classify an email as spam based on its subject and body text?

**Edit:** I have already seen methods on how to do this in Python, but I am asking, can anyone provide any Encog + C# specific examples of how to create a spam filtering/classifying application?

Comment: @JeffHeaton Are you out there!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most spam filters use a sort of Bayesian classification, most popular, naïve Bayesian classification.
Here is some code that can be used without any additional frameworks.

```
public void TrainClassifier(DataTable table)
{
dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

//table
DataTable GaussianDistribution = dataSet.Tables.Add("Gaussian");
GaussianDistribution.Columns.Add(table.Columns[0].ColumnName);

//columns
for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    GaussianDistribution.Columns.Add(table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "Mean");
    GaussianDistribution.Columns.Add(table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "Variance");
}

//calc data
var results = (from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
               group myRow by myRow.Field<string>(table.Columns[0].ColumnName) into g
               select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();

for (int j = 0; j < results.Count; j++)
{
    DataRow row = GaussianDistribution.Rows.Add();
    row[0] = results[j].Name;

    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        row[a] = Helper.Mean(SelectRows(table, i, string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", 
                             table.Columns[0].ColumnName, results[j].Name)));
        row[++a] = Helper.Variance(SelectRows(table, i, 
                   string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", 
                   table.Columns[0].ColumnName, results[j].Name)));
        a++;
    }
}
```

}

```
public string Classify(double[] obj)
{
Dictionary<string,> score = new Dictionary<string,>();

var results = (from myRow in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
               group myRow by myRow.Field<string>(
                     dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName) into g
               select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
    List<double> subScoreList = new List<double>();
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k < dataSet.Tables["Gaussian"].Columns.Count; k = k + 2)
    {
        double mean = Convert.ToDouble(dataSet.Tables["Gaussian"].Rows[i][a]);
        double variance = Convert.ToDouble(dataSet.Tables["Gaussian"].Rows[i][++a]);
        double result = Helper.NormalDist(obj[b - 1], mean, Helper.SquareRoot(variance));
        subScoreList.Add(result);
        a++; b++;
    }

    double finalScore = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < subScoreList.Count; z++)
    {
        if (finalScore == 0)
        {
            finalScore = subScoreList[z];
            continue;
        }

        finalScore = finalScore * subScoreList[z];
    }

    score.Add(results[i].Name, finalScore * 0.5);
}

double maxOne = score.Max(c => c.Value);
var name = (from c in score
            where c.Value == maxOne
            select c.Key).First();

return name;
}
```

EDIT:Heres how you use it!

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
    table.Columns.Add("Sex"); 
    table.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(double)); 
    table.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(double)); 
    table.Columns.Add("FootSize", typeof(double)); 

    //training data. 
    table.Rows.Add("male", 6, 180, 12); 
    table.Rows.Add("male", 5.92, 190, 11); 
    table.Rows.Add("male", 5.58, 170, 12); 
    table.Rows.Add("male", 5.92, 165, 10); 
    table.Rows.Add("female", 5, 100, 6); 
    table.Rows.Add("female", 5.5, 150, 8); 
    table.Rows.Add("female", 5.42, 130, 7); 
    table.Rows.Add("female", 5.75, 150, 9); 
    table.Rows.Add("transgender", 4, 200, 5); 
    table.Rows.Add("transgender", 4.10, 150, 8); 
    table.Rows.Add("transgender", 5.42, 190, 7); 
    table.Rows.Add("transgender", 5.50, 150, 9);

    Classifier classifier = new Classifier(); 
    classifier.TrainClassifier(table);
    //output would be transgender.
    Console.WriteLine(classifier.Classify(new double[] { 4, 150, 12 }));
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer when no one else would.  I was trying to study your code, but I have two questions:  1) How would I initialize the `dataSet` variable in order to run a test?  2) What type of object do I pass to the Classify() method to return the result?  I am just trying to find a way to run this code to see it working in action.

Comment: Edited the post :) hope this also answers your Classify() question too.

Comment: Thanks for your code.  I am not immediately sure how I would apply this to spam filtering; but, maybe as I continue to learn that will become more clear.

Comment: You should find a a collection of spam emails and retrieve each word and its frequency for example. Using frequency as a input node, you can calculate the prob of email being spam. I suggest looking for html tags.

Comment: Can you show what's inside the Helper.Mean and Helper.Variance methods?